# Socket client for two servers in C

Tags: c, sockets, client

In my C program I need to communicate with two servers, one at IP=X1 PORT=X2 and one server at IP=Y1, PORT=Y2. I.e. I would like to be able to write and read to/from the two servers in my program. 
E.g.

```
write(Server1,buffer1);
read(Server1,buffer1);
write(Server2,buffer2);
read(Server2,buffer2);
```

I know how to create a single socket client for communication with one server but I'm not sure how the code should look like for communication with two. Anybody that guide me in the right direction/show me an example?

Best regards Simon

Comment: Maybe you can use `fork`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry for bad English and for give a Windows code, I could not write in Linux for now for strong reasons but I hope to do that in the next time.

Although a windows version may be a little scarying at first, it will be clear if you read the code carefully. Also, you must make some changes from Windows to POSIX Linux version, what is very direct (for examples, using POSIX threads instead windows threads).

I have created to sockets to receive connections and change messages in pattern recv-send as you expected. Each server may receive the number of connections limited by MAX_THREADS (each thread managing one connection). Note that select() returns the server socket that has a pending connection to call accept().

```
#include <winSock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <processthreadsapi.h>
#include <heapapi.h>

#define MAX_THREADS 20
#define MAX_BUFF_SIZE 256

struct thread_list
{
    HANDLE thread;
    struct thread_list *next;
};

struct MyData {
    char name_server[8];
    int sock;
};

void log_error(char *msg)
{
    printf(msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void initSocket(int *server, struct sockaddr_in *addr, char *ip, uint16_t porta){

    if ((*server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0){
        log_error("Erro socket\n");
    }

    addr->sin_port = htons(porta);
    addr->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
    addr->sin_family = AF_INET;

    if((bind(*server, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0))
        log_error("ERROR bind()");

    if(listen(*server, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        log_error("error listen()");

    return;
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunc(void *data)
{
    char messageFrom[MAX_BUFF_SIZE], messageTo[MAX_BUFF_SIZE];
    struct MyData *ptr = (struct MyData *)data;

    // pattern: recv - send
    while(1)
    {
        recv(ptr->sock, messageFrom, MAX_BUFF_SIZE, 0);

        printf(messageFrom);

        strcpy(messageTo, "Message received. Complete send() message in your way");

        send(ptr->sock, messageTo, strlen(messageTo), 0);
    }

    // Save the whales, feed the hungry, free the mallocs()'s
}


int main( int argc, char **argv) {
    struct sockaddr_in addr1, addr2; 

    int server1, server2;

    struct MyData *pDataArray[MAX_THREADS];
    DWORD   dwThreadIdArray[MAX_THREADS];
    HANDLE  hThreadArray[MAX_THREADS]; 

    // init num current active threads
    int num_threads = 0;

    if(argc < 5)
        log_error("Format: ./prog ip1 port1 ip2 port2\n");

    initSocket(&server1, &addr1, argv[1], (uint16_t)atoi(argv[2]));
    initSocket(&server2, &addr2, argv[3], (uint16_t)atoi(argv[4]));

    int evtsock, novosock;

    fd_set readfds;

    FD_SET(server1, &readfds);
    FD_SET(server2, &readfds);

    struct sockaddr their_addr;
    socklen_t strg_sz = sizeof(their_addr);

    while(1) { //escuta conexoes

        evtsock = select(0, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        pDataArray[num_threads]->sock = accept(evtsock, &their_addr, &strg_sz);

        if(pDataArray[num_threads]->sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
            log_error("ERROR accept()");

        if(num_threads == MAX_THREADS){
            // now this program will run forever. It is recommended to manage signals like SIGTERM
            // free mallocated memory and release all resources carefully
            printf("Max connections reached\n");
            continue;
        }

        pDataArray[num_threads] = (struct MyData *) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY,
            sizeof(struct MyData));

        if(evtsock == server1)
            strcpy(pDataArray[num_threads]->name_server, "server1");
        else if(evtsock == server1)
            strcpy(pDataArray[num_threads]->name_server, "server2");
        else
            printf("Unmanaged event\n");

        hThreadArray[num_threads] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunc, &pDataArray[num_threads], 0, NULL);

        num_threads++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```